# Retrofit2 strange combination of different braces in front of request Body

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, gson

I am using **Retrofit2** and I got stuck on the problem. I wrote simple entity for body:

```
data class DateRequest(
@JsonAdapter(RetrofitDateSerializer::class)
@SerializedName("date") @Expose val date: OffsetDateTime)
```

also I wrote custom serializer for it:

```
class RetrofitDateSerializer : JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
override fun serialize(
    srcDate: OffsetDateTime?,
    typeOfSrc: Type?,
    context: JsonSerializationContext?
): JsonElement? {
    val formatted = DateTimeUtil.convertFromDateTime(srcDate!!)
    return JsonPrimitive(formatted)
}}
```

**DateTimeUtil**:

```
fun convertFromDateTime(dateTime: OffsetDateTime): String {
    val formatter = formatDateTime()
    return formatter.format(dateTime)
}
fun formatDateTime(): DateTimeFormatter {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withLocale(Locale.US)
}
```

and in request body somehow appears this:

```
)]}'{"date": "2018-12-07 06:00:00"}
```

How this "**)]}'**" could be attached at front of my "**date**" json in request?

```
@POST("changecleaning/{userId}/{cleaningId}/{status}")
fun changeCleaning(
    @Path("userId") userId: Long,
    @Path("cleaningId") cleaningId: Long,
    @Path("status") status: Int,
    @Body date: DateRequest
): Maybe<Status>
```

Only that I found is after **JsonWriter** do some magic in **buffer.readByteString()** it stores broken body.

***GsonRequestBodyConverter***:

```
@Override public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer);
    adapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
    jsonWriter.close();
    return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString());
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was the problem comes from:

Here my custom **GsonBuilder**:

```
private fun getGsonFactory(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()
            .setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.DEFAULT)
            .generateNonExecutableJson()
            .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
            .serializeNulls()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .registerTypeAdapter(CleaningProgress::class.java, CleaningProgressDeserializer())
            .create()
    }
```

The line of code below, add that "**)]}'**" at front of request. Why am I add it to builder? I trust official documentation about this method:

> Makes the output JSON non-executable in Javascript by prefixing the generated JSON with some special text. This prevents attacks from third-party sites through script sourcing.

```
.generateNonExecutableJson()
```

Now my **GsonBuilder** looks like this:

```
private fun getGsonFactory(): Gson {
    return GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .registerTypeAdapter(CleaningProgress::class.java, CleaningProgressDeserializer())
        .create()
}
```